# Get PHP to run code contained in a string

Tags: php

You have a string, which contains a snippet of PHP code:

```
$run_me = "echo ('Hello World!!');";
```

How can you get PHP to run the code, contained in $run_me?

You can't do:

```
include ($run_me);
```

That would include the *path* $run_me, so what's the solution?

Comment: [`eval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php).

Comment: This seems like a homework type question. If it is, I hope to lord php that it's covered at some point as to why Eval  Is evil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to use `eval()`. This will execute the string you enter as PHP code.